# react threw the error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React is returning the error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length')" when I execute the application but I cannot figure out what should I do to fix it.

The problem is at line 51 in the App component where it is showing an error in the footer component for passing the value of length as {items.length}. Here is the code:

```
import Header from './Header';
import AddItem from './AddItem';
import Content from './Content';
import Footer from './Footer';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppinglist')));
  const [newItem, setNewItem] = useState('')
  const setAndSaveItems = (newItems) => {
    setItems(newItems);
    localStorage.setItem('shoppinglist', JSON.stringify(newItems));
  }

  const addItem = (item) => {
    const id = items.length ? items[items.length - 1].id + 1 : 1;
    const myNewItem = { id, checked: false, item };
    const listItems = [...items, myNewItem];
    setAndSaveItems(listItems);
  }

  const handleCheck = (id) => {
    const listItems = items.map((item) => item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item);
    setAndSaveItems(listItems);
  }

  const handleDelete = (id) => {
    const listItems = items.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
    setAndSaveItems(listItems);
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!newItem) return;
    addItem(newItem);
    setNewItem('');
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header title="Grocery List" />
      <AddItem
        newItem={newItem}
        setNewItem={setNewItem}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
      />
      <Content
        handleCheck={handleCheck}
        handleDelete={handleDelete}
      />
      <Footer length={items.length} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I will greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: You should assign a suitable default value to items, assuming that the shopping list doesn’t exist in local storage

Comment: As pointed out by @James.   `useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppinglist')) ?? []);`